# C++ : Operator Overloading, operator+

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
#include"polynom.h"
using namespace std;

// operator= works !!!

int main()
{
    Polynomial p(5), q(5), r(5);
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 2;
    p[2] = 3;

    q[0] = 4;
    q[1] = 5;
    q[2] = 6;

    cout<<p+q;
    return 0;
}


Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &copyConstructor) : size(copyConstructor.size)
{ 
    coeffs = new double(size);

    int i=0;
    while(i<size)
    {
        coeffs[i] = copyConstructor.coeffs[i];
        i++;
    }
} 


Polynomial::Polynomial(int s)
{
    size = s;
    coeffs = new double [s];

    // Setting all coefficients in the polynomial equal to 0 
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        coeffs[i]=0;
}



Polynomial Polynomial::operator+ (const Polynomial &rightPoly) const
{

    int BigSize, SmallSize;
    Polynomial *newPoly = NULL;

    cout<<"in the operator\n";

    if(size == rightPoly.size)
    {
        cout<<"first if\n";
        newPoly = new Polynomial(size);

        cout<<"first if resize\n";
        for(int i=0; i<newPoly->size; i++)
            cout<<newPoly->coeffs[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"size = "<<size<<endl;
        cout<<"rightPoly.size = "<<rightPoly.size<<endl;
        cout<<"newPoly->size = "<<newPoly->size<<endl;

        cout<<"first if loop\n";
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout<<"i= "<<i;
            newPoly->coeffs[i] = rightPoly.coeffs[i]+coeffs[i];
            cout<<" newPoly[]"<<newPoly->coeffs[i]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"out of loop\n"<<endl;
    }


    else if(size > rightPoly.size)
    {
        cout<<"second if\n";
        BigSize = size;
        SmallSize = rightPoly.size;

        newPoly = new Polynomial(BigSize);

        cout<<"second if loop\n";
        for(int i=0; i<SmallSize; i++)
            newPoly->coeffs[i] = rightPoly.coeffs[i] + coeffs[i];
        for(int i=SmallSize; i<BigSize; i++)
            newPoly->coeffs[i] = coeffs[i];
        cout<<"second if loop end\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"third if\n";
        BigSize = rightPoly.size;
        SmallSize = size;

        newPoly = new Polynomial(BigSize);

        for(int i=0; i<SmallSize; i++)
            newPoly->coeffs[i] = coeffs[i] + rightPoly.coeffs[i];
        for(int i=SmallSize; i<BigSize; i++)
            newPoly->coeffs[i] = rightPoly.coeffs[i];
    }

    cout<<"before return\n";
    return *newPoly;    
}
```

Problem:
When Visual Studio 2010 executes p+q line, it gives the following error. p and q have both same sizes and they are initialized properly (I checked both of them).

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in CNG242.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in CNG242.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while CNG242.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

I added comments in order to follow the lines and find out where the problem is. I did not get what causes the error?

Comment: Does your class have a proper copy constructor?

Comment: Make sure you are following the Rule of Three.

Comment: I don't really see the point of using a pointer for `newPoly`. Just create one and return it from each if block, or add/use a `setSize` function.

Comment: @AdamRossenfield 
I added my copy constructor.

Comment: @chirs
Creating newPoly in each if statement(since the size depends...) and then returning it did not solve the problem

Comment: @Nicol Bolas

p+q is line is added to the code.

Comment: @user1183220, I didn't say it would, but allocating things on the stack is usually more preferable than using pointers. No need to clean up or anything.

Comment: You should show all the code that you call and wrote, including the `operator[]` code.

Comment: I found the problem. As Adam Rosenfield said, copy constructor has some problems and I correct them. 

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Even though you've solved the problem, you should also fix the fact that you're heap-allocating with `new`, then de-referencing that pointer and returning it by value.

Comment: +1 to chris. Unless you have a *really* good reason to use "new", don't. It's one of those Java habits that seriously hurts when using C++. Besides, cutting back the code example to the *significant* part (i.e., leaving out code that does not contribute to the problem, without leaving out important things like the copy constructor) is an artform you should practice. In most cases, reducing the code example to what is really *necessary* to exhibit the bug will give you the solution right away.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
coeffs = new double(size);
```

allocates space for *one* `double` variable, initialises its value to `size`, and returns the pointer to `coeffs`. What you probably want is:

```
coeffs = new double[size];
```

Note the square brackets. This initializes space for `size` doubles, does not initialise them to anything in particular, and returns a pointer to the first one to `coeffs`.

Answer (score 0):

You overflowed the heap block

```
coeffs = new double(size); // You allocated memory for only one double variable
```

this way.